# Uploading PNG to Website Server

Tags: php, mysql, image, png

I have seen loads of other topics and I've tried them all. Can someone please help with why this script won't upload PNG files? Blank PNG image being displayed.

```
$image = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$image_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($image_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$location = "Profiles/{$user}/Picture/{$image_name}";

$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);

$source_image = imagecreatefrompng($image);

imagealphablending($source_image, false);
imagesavealpha($source_image, true);
imagealphablending($new_image, false);
imagesavealpha($new_image, true);

imagecopyresampled($new_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100, $image_width, $image_height);

imagepng($new_image, '../' . $location, 9);
```

Comment: Are you doing any error checking?

Comment: No error checks as the exact same code, but for JPG, works great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not declaring `$image_width` or  `$image-height` and you are referencing `$image` instead of `$source_image` in `imagecopyresampled()`.

I too was getting a plain white image, but after this I get the expected result:

```
$image = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$image_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($image_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$location = "Profiles/{$user}/Picture/{$image_name}";

$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);

$source_image = imagecreatefrompng($image);

// Get the width & height of the uploaded image.
$image_width = imagesx($source_image);
$image_height = imagesy($source_image);

imagealphablending($source_image, false);
imagesavealpha($source_image, true);
imagealphablending($new_image, false);
imagesavealpha($new_image, true);

imagecopyresampled($new_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100, $image_width, $image_height);

imagepng($new_image, '../' . $location, 9);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am declaring the image size but I didn't put that code into the example. Still not working...

Comment: The above works for me when also adding a `$user` & valid `$location`. Enable error reporting with this at the top of your page: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`.

Comment: Dude, I'm getting this error: _Warning: imagecopyresampled(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in /hsphere/local/home/james9322/three-lions-gaming.co.uk/Account/action_edit.php on line 59_

Comment: Ah sorry my fault. Forgot to point out in my code above that I also had to change `imagecopyresampled($new_image, $image, 0, ...` to `imagecopyresampled($new_image, $source_image, 0, ...`. You were referencing the path to the uploaded file and not the reference to the sampled image.

Comment: Dude, you are literally my favourite person for the whole week! Thanks so much, you've been a great help!